# make environment variable available inside cmd script in windows

Tags: windows, shell, windows-server-2008-r2, environment-variables

I am running a script like below, but the environment variable path does not contain C:\tmp inside script.cmd, how to make it available?
Os is windows.

```
cmd.exe /c "set path=%path%;C:\tmp && script.cmd"
```

EDIT:
script.cmd

```
echo %path%
somefile.exe
```

After some struggle, echo command working for me, but when I execute some executable which are present in C:\tmp inside script.cmd, I am getting "command not found" error

Comment: Not reproducible. Please [edit] your question to include the contents of `script.cmd`

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Your command line works **Okay** for me too, must be something in the script.cmd